# Key ... is not present in table ... but it's. (Copy Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, copy, key

When a try:

```
copy qe_direito_incidencia from 'C:\\temp\\Direito_Incidencia_04-04-17.txt' with delimiter E'\t' null as '';
```

I have this error:

> ```
> ERROR: insert or update on table "qe_direito_incidencia" violates foreign key constraint "qe_direito_incidencia_cod_empresa_fkey"
> SQL state: 23503
> Detail: Key (cod_empresa, cod_direito)=(1, 78) is not present in table "qe_direito".
> ```

But I have this record in the two tables, qe_direito and qe_direito_incidencia.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: what you see when you `select count(*) from qe_direito where cod_empresa = 1 and cod_direito=78`?..

Comment: There it is! I have this record, but when I try to use 'copy', I got ERROR: insert or update on table "qe_direito_incidencia" violates foreign key constraint "qe_direito_incidencia_cod_empresa_fkey" SQL state: 23503 Detail: Key (cod_empresa, cod_direito)=(1, 78) is not present in table "qe_direito".

Comment: please update with the result of `begin; select count(*) from qe_direito where cod_empresa = 1 and cod_direito=78; copy qe_direito_incidencia from 'C:\\temp\\Direito_Incidencia_04-04-17.txt' with delimiter E'\t' null as ''; end;`

Comment: ERROR:  insert or update on table "qe_direito_incidencia" violates foreign key constraint "qe_direito_incidencia_cod_empresa_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (cod_empresa, cod_direito)=(1, 78) is not present in table "qe_direito".

Comment: The same thing.

Comment: it's not the result of my last query

Comment: This -> select count(*) from qe_direito where cod_empresa = 1 and cod_direito=78 
RETURNS 1.

Comment: please update with the result of `begin; select count(*) from qe_direito where cod_empresa = 1 and cod_direito=78; copy qe_direito_incidencia from 'C:\\temp\\Direito_Incidencia_04-04-17.txt' with delimiter E'\t' null as ''; end;`

Comment: I did it, but:
ERROR:  insert or update on table "qe_direito_incidencia" violates foreign key constraint "qe_direito_incidencia_cod_empresa_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (cod_empresa, cod_direito)=(1, 78) is not present in table "qe_direito".
********** Error **********

ERROR: insert or update on table "qe_direito_incidencia" violates foreign key constraint "qe_direito_incidencia_cod_empresa_fkey"
SQL state: 23503
Detail: Key (cod_empresa, cod_direito)=(1, 78) is not present in table "qe_direito".

Comment: I've solved. But I needed to change the export excel to CSV. When I try to export this like TXT, it doesn't work and report the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved. But I needed to change the export excel to CSV. When I try to export this like TXT, it doesn't work and report the error above.